# Modal stops working after image changes on page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im building an app where you can like and dislike movies. I have a database of movies and show each one to the user. When you click like or dislike it takes you to the next poster.

I also have access to the description and rating. I've added my own modal to show the user when clicked more information on that movie.

The problem Im having is the modal works for the first movie and changes the class to active. However on the second one it stops working. I can see in the inspector the modal code is there and has the correct information for that movie. But the modal seems to still not work/become unresponsive. Perhaps its an error that I've missed. I notice that it does add active once again on the first item. Perhaps I need to find a way to switch to the current movie instead or incorporate the modal into the slides more? or find a way to reset it..

EDIT -:
Adding to the above. Having done a bit more testing. It seems like the modal doesnt know what id the slide is on.. So it never knows when the slide is changed.. Any ideas how I would do this?

EDIT2 -:
I've now got it so every modal has a unique id per poster using the contact.id. Any way to link the modal id together with the slides so when I change the slide the modal knows and changes to active on the next slide?

```js
const modalBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-btn");
const modalBg = document.querySelectorAll("movie-modal");
const modalClose = document.querySelectorAll(".close-button");
const overlay = document.querySelectorAll("overlay");
const overlayClose = document.querySelectorAll("overlay");
const activeModal = document.querySelectorAll(".movie-modal:first-child")

modalBtn.forEach(function(btn, index){
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(click) {
    console.log(click)
    modalBg.classList.add('active');
    overlay.classList.add('active');
    var content_id = activeModal.data("id");
    console.log(content_id)
  });
});

modalClose.forEach(function(btn, index){
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(click) {
    console.log(click)
    modalBg.classList.remove('active');
    overlay.classList.remove('active');
  });
});

overlay.forEach(function(overlay, index){
  overlay.addEventListener('click', function() {
  overlayClose.classList.remove('active');
  });
});

overlay.forEach(function(overlay, index){
  overlay.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.movie-modal.active')
  modals.forEach(modal => {
    modal.classList.remove('active');
    overlay.classList.remove('active');
    })
  })
});

$(function(){
  var $activeSlide = $('#slides .slide:first-child');

  // show first slide
  $activeSlide.addClass("active");
  // on click event decline
  $("#decline").on("click", function(){
    goToSlide('decline');
  });
  // on click approve then what?
  $("#approve").on("click", function(){
    var content_id = $activeSlide.data("id");
    console.log(content_id)
    goToSlide('approve');
    // $.ajax({
    //   url: "/user_contents/liked" + content_id,
    //   method: "post",
    //   dataType: "ajax"
    // });
  });
    // adding the 'showing' or 'active' slide class to each element
  function goToSlide(action) {
    $activeSlide.removeClass("active");
    $activeSlide = $activeSlide.next(".slide");

    // send data to controller
    if(action == "approve"){
      console.log(action);
    } else {
      console.log('dislike');
    }
    $activeSlide.addClass("active");
  }

});
```

```css
.movie-modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 80%;
  color: black;
}
.movie-modal.active{
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
.movie-modal-header {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(182, 182, 182);
}

.movie-rating {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.movie-modal-body {
  padding: 16px;
  color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#overlay.active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

#slide-controls {
  margin: 20px 0 400px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #ffffffba;
  font-size: 24px;
  top: 50%;
}
.image-carousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 642px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size:  contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
#decline {
  margin-left: 16px;
}
#approve {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.img-thumbnail {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
    <ul id="slides">
      <% @contents.each_with_index do |content, i| %>
      <li class="slide <%= 'active' if i == 0 %>" data-id="<%= content.id %>">
        <div class="image-carousel" style="background-image: url('<%= content.poster %>')">
        </div>
        <button class="modal-btn">Open Modal</button>
          <div id="movie-modal <%= content.id %>" class="movie-modal">
            <div class="movie-modal-header">
              <div class="movie-rating" style="">Average rating: <strong><%= content.rating %></strong></div>
              <button class="close-button">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="movie-modal-body"><p><%= content.description %></p></div>
          </div>

          <div id="overlay <%= content.id %>"></div>
      </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>


  <div id="slide-controls">
    <span id="decline"><i class="fa fa-solid fa-thumbs-down fa-2x"></i></span>
    <span id="approve"><i class="fa fa-solid fa-thumbs-up fa-2x"></i></span>
  </div>
```

[This shows when the first poster is clicked the modal works and movie-modal active is added to the modal class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOJxt.png)

[The second image with Morbius in it.. The modal class doesnt change for the current slide showing however it changes for the previous slide.. BUT the previous slide only changes once and then sticks to active. Nothing is shown on the poster.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ9vI.png)

Comment: Please fix your code snippet, it currently gives an error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Remember that we cannot execute ASP script in the Snippet. Please supply the resulting HTML.

Comment: Not really sure how to do it as its the whole function of the app. Should I upload the routes, controllers, models etc? Perhaps I leave the code up and make a video/photo?